# Building Angular 5 project with CLI using ng build --prod

Tags: angular5

When I building my angular 5 project using

```
ng build --prod
```

It gives long error as below. It shows part of error.

```
error TS5055: Cannot write file 'E:/Files/dash- 
functional/node_modules/zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone.js' because it 
would overwrite in
put file.
Adding a tsconfig.json file will help organize projects that contain both 
TypeScript and JavaScript files. Learn more at https://aka.ms/t
sconfig.
error TS5055: Cannot write file 'E:/Files/dash- 
functional/node_modules/zone.js/dist/proxy.js' because it would overwrite 
input file.
Adding a tsconfig.json file will help organize projects that contain both 
TypeScript and JavaScript files. Learn more at https://aka.ms/t
sconfig.
error TS5055: Cannot write file 'E:/Files/dash- 
functional/node_modules/zone.js/dist/sync-test.js' because it would 
overwrite input file.
Adding a tsconfig.json file will help organize projects that contain both 
TypeScript and JavaScript files. Learn more at https://aka.ms/t
sconfig.
error TS5055: Cannot write file 'E:/Files/dash- 
functional/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js' because it would overwrite 
input file.
Adding a tsconfig.json file will help organize projects that contain both 
TypeScript and JavaScript files. Learn more at https://aka.ms/t
sconfig.
```

After I added tsconfig.json as below also gives error again.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
"target": "es5",
"module": "commonjs",
"moduleResolution": "node",
"sourceMap": true,
"emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
"experimentalDecorators": true,
"lib": [ "es2015", "dom" ],
"noImplicitAny": true,
"suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
  }
}
```

How can I solve this. That error is not showing when compiling (ng serve) and build without prod mode.(ng build)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the TypeScript compiler is processing the `.ts` files in your `node_modules` folder. You'll need to add an `exclude` array in your `.tsconfig` file. You can learn more about the `.tsconfig` file in the [TypeScript docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html).

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {...},
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

How did you create your Angular project? If you use the Angular CLI, it will create this file for you already. You may want to generate an example project using the Angular CLI and copy/paste the `.tsconfig` file it generates (maybe even use that as a starting point for your project).

Comment: That is my corrected tsconfig. But it also gives same error. {
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
]
}

Comment: Thank you for response. After edit tsconfig and update node version in project, problem is solved.